# How do actions work in Ember Mixins?

Tags: javascript, ember.js, promise, ember-cli

I am trying to develop my first mixin but I'm having trouble getting the actions to play nicely.

I want my controllers to be able to toggle an `editing` property and to set it to false when the model is saved or rolled back. So I've written a mixin to add this capability.

in `myapp/mixins/editable.js`:

```
import Ember from "ember";

export default Ember.Mixin.create({
  editing: false,

  actions: {
    toggleEditing: function() {
      this.toggleProperty('editing');
    },
    cancel: function () {
      console.log("editable mixin: cancel");
      this.set('editing', false);
      return true;
    },
    save: function () {
      console.log("editable mixin: save");
      this.set('editing', false);
      return true;
    }
  }
});
```

I thought this would be great as I can have consistent edit buttons in my templates like this.

in `myapp/templates/sometemplate.hbs`:

```
{{#if editing}}
  {{#if model.isDirty}}
    <button class="action-icon" {{action "cancel"}}>{{fa-icon "times" title="discard changes"}}</button>
    <button class="action-icon" {{action "save"}}>{{fa-icon "save" title="save changes"}}</button>
  {{else}}
    <button class="action-icon" {{action "toggleEditing"}}>{{fa-icon "times" title="cancel"}}</button>
  {{/if}}
{{else}}
  <button class="action-icon" {{action "toggleEditing"}}>{{fa-icon "pencil" title="edit"}}</button>
{{/if}}
```

...and I can control saving and cancelling in my route, something like this:

in `myapp/route/someroute.js`:

```
import Ember from "ember";

export default Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function(params) {
    return this.store.find('somemodel', params.model_id);
  },
  actions: {
    save: function () {
      console.log("route: save");
      this.modelFor('somemodel').save();
    },
    cancel: function () {
      console.log("route: cancel");
      this.modelFor('somemodel').rollback();
    },
  }
});
```

However, I am now confused... what happens if the save fails? How can I plumb it together so that the `editing` property is set to false *only* when the save has successfully completed?

Is there some way to access a promise from an action on the route? Am I heading in the right direction with this?

Answer (score 4):

This is possible, but there's a little bit of weirdness. [Here is a JSBin](http://emberjs.jsbin.com/xoqefefene/1/edit?js,console) demonstrating the concept. Applied to your code, you'll have to do this:

```
const SomeRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    actions: {
        save() {
            return this.modelFor('somemodel').save();
        }
    }
});

SomeRoute.reopen(EditableMixin);

export default SomeRoute;
```

Then, in your Mixin:

```
export default Mixin.create({
    actions: {
        save() {
            this._super().then(() => {
                this.set('editing', false);
            });
        }
    }
});
```

Note that if you apply the mixin at extend time, the super chain won't be set up correctly, so you'll have to reopen the route to apply the mixin.

Comment: The key seems to be calling `this._super` in the action. Would this apply if I implemented a save action in an intermediate controller? I'm not clear on how this interacts with the "bubbling" behaviour. I guess I should try to understand this extend vs reopen stuff. It does seem like weirdness.

Comment: The concepts are a bit confusing, but distinct. Bubbling actions is when an action goes from one class to another. For example: component -> controller -> route. But `_super` actions only call actions in the _same_ class that have been overridden. So in my example, if you return `true` from the mixin action, it will call the super method defined in the route, then bubble the action to the next highest route in the chain. You most likely do _not_ want to bubble actions here. (My advice: never bubble actions unless you absolutely _know_ you need to.)